# powershell Script for unzipping in specific named folder

Tags: powershell

I have several zip files which have generated names like `21321421-12315-sad3fse-23434fg-ggfsd` which doesn't help to identify the content of the zip.

I need a script, which unzips it and then looks for a pdf file with a partly-generated & static name eg `asdawd-ersrfse-231-Formular2311`.

After that it should create a folder with the name of the pdf file and unzip all zip-file content into this folder.

So far I only have to snippets that work after each other, but I'm still stuck.

```
$shell = new-object -com shell.application
$CurrentLocation = get-location
$CurrentPath = $CurrentLocation.path
$Location = $shell.namespace($CurrentPath)

# Find all the Zip files and Count them
$ZipFiles = get-childitem -Path "C:\Install\NB\Teststart" *.zip
$ZipFiles.count | out-default

# Set the Index for unique folders
$Index = 1

# For every zip file in the folder
foreach ($ZipFile in $ZipFiles) {

    # Get the full path to the zip file
    $ZipFile.fullname | out-default

    # Set the location and create a new folder to unzip the files into - Edit the line below to change the location to save files to
    $NewLocation = "C:\Install\NB\Testfinal\$Index"
    New-Item $NewLocation -type Directory

    # Move the zip file to the new folder so that you know which was the original file (can be changed to Copy-Item if needed)
    Copy-Item $ZipFile.fullname $NewLocation

    # List up all of the zip files in the new folder 
    $NewZipFile = get-childitem $NewLocation *.zip

    # Get the COMObjects required for the unzip process
    $NewLocation = $shell.namespace($NewLocation)
    $ZipFolder = $shell.namespace($NewZipFile.fullname)

    # Copy the files to the new Folder
    $NewLocation.copyhere($ZipFolder.items())

    # Increase the Index to ensure that unique folders are made
    $Index = $Index + 1
}

Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Install\NB\Testfinal" -Include "*.pdf" -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $oldFolder = $_.DirectoryName

    # New Folder Name is .pdf Filename, excluding extension
    $newFolder = $_.Name.Substring(0, $_.Name.Length - 4)

    # Verify Not Already Same Name
    Write-Host "Rename: $oldFolder To: $newFolder"
    Rename-Item -NewName $newFolder -Path $oldFolder
}
```

Comment: Is the 'static' part of the name the same for every zip file? Is there only one pdf in each zip?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help;
yeah the static part is always the same and in each zip file is only one pdf and several XML Files

Comment: What version of Powershell are you using? Run `$PSVersionTable` to check if you don't know..

Comment: Version 5 on Server 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along the same lines as your own script, firstly extract the zips and then rename the extracted folder to the same as the pdf:

```
$SourceDir = 'C:\Install\NB\Teststart'
$ExtractDir = 'C:\Install\NB\Testfinal'

# Extract each zip to a folder with the same name as the zip file (BaseName)
Get-ChildItem (Join-Path $SourceDir *.zip) | foreach {
    Expand-Archive $_.FullName -DestinationPath (Join-Path $ExtractDir $_.BaseName)
}

# Rename the PDF's parent folder to the same as the PDF
Get-ChildItem (Join-Path $ExtractDir *.pdf) -Recurse | foreach {
    Rename-Item -Path $_.Directory.FullName -NewName $_.BaseName
}
```

Comment: i knew, that this can be done much easier. thank you so much - it works like a charm

Comment: Glad I could help, if you're happy with my answer you can [Mark it as Accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: hi, one more little question: is it possible to send the content of each renamed folder additionally with an email? i have the working send command, but don't get it working with the folders, i only know how to specify certain filenames

Comment: Yes it's certainly possible. As this question has been marked as answered, I would create a new question :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do and it's much simpler than what you have. It relies on .NET 4.5 which you should have on your server already:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.IO.Compression.FileSystem')

# Get all the zip files in the root of the script, change $PSScriptRoot accordingly
Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot -Filter *.zip -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    # Open the archive for reading
    $zip = [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($_.FullName)

    # Find the name of the PD file from the archive entries
    $archiveName = $zip.Entries | `
        Where-Object { [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($_.FullName) -eq '.pdf' } | `
        Select-Object @{N = "BaseName"; E = {[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.FullName)}} |
        Select-Object -Expand BaseName

    # Close the zip file
    $zip.Dispose()

    # Use the native Expand-Archive to unzip the archive
    # Ammand $PSScriptRoot to the destination base path if needed
    Expand-Archive -Path $_.FullName -DestinationPath (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot $archiveName)
}
```